# How to rotate the camera to point to a specified location?

Tags: opengl, 3d, camera

I have a quaternion based camera class (which controls a view matrix) and would like a function to rotate the camera to face a specified point. The best approach I can come up with is that I rotate the camera on the plane of the two vector by the angle between them.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

Any decent OpenGL math library should have a function called `lookAt`. It does exactly what you want with the exception that it produces a matrix and not a quaternion. This problem can be solved by converting the matrix back to a quaternion.

In case you aren't already using a math library, I recommend checking [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/index.html) which basically tries to provide everything that GLSL has, just in C++.